# Скрипт звонков с сайта на телефон

Tags: скрипт, php

Здравствуйте! Нужен скрипт для звонков с сайта на телефон. Я вообще впервые такое ищу. Кто с этим знаком, подскажите, или направьте в нужное направление.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, напрямую с сайта звонить на телефон у Вас вряд ли получится. Нужно разворачивать АТС, затем внедрять в страницу скрипт, который будет взаимодействовать с ее API.